# Is it possible to formalize areas such as image processing and computer vision?

Tags: logic, axioms, image-processing

Is it possible to formalize areas such as image processing?

By formalize I mean setup axioms, then derive theorems, and
reason about image processing concepts and methods formally.
I would say now image processing is pretty informal and ill-defined
without strong foundations.

Comment: Do you mean image processing like compressing a JPEG, or image processing like inferring 3D shapes from a 2D image or movie?

Answer (score 1):

Mumford got interested; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Mumford  and [http://www.amazon.com/Pattern-Theory-Stochastic-Real-World-Mathematics/dp/1568815794/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1568815794) and many vision pdfs at http://www.dam.brown.edu/people/mumford/vision/papers/

Anyway, theory, such as you request, and practice are currently very far apart. You might look up "persistent homology" for example.

Comment: @PeterSheldrick, I try not to worry too much about what an OP explicitly asks, especially when I know absolutely nothing about their background. On the other side, Mumford's involvement is the totality of what I know about this topic; I heard him lecture about it, about 2003... This topic seems to matter to you; perhaps you could work up a more elaborate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would beg to disagree.  Image processing is quite formal.  Images are treated as discrete functions in 2D, and are manipulated using very formal methods from calculus, linear algebra, and statistics.